# VB .NET XDocument and using IIF

Tags: vb.net

I've just got to know XDocument in VB .NET and really like the way I can write XML documents in my code but have just one little problem I can't find a good solution for. The problem is with IIF that I use to check some conditions for example if a node should be printed or not.

The problem is when I want to print multiple nodes (from a list of strings) if my conditions are true first. Here is the problem code where I'm checking few conditions and in true part I'll try to loop nodes:

```
<%= IIf(settings.UseInvoiceFreeText _
OrElse settings.BuyerIntermediatorCode = "" _
OrElse settings.BuyerIntermediatorCode = "", _
      <%= From freeText As String In InvoiceFreeTexts
       Select <InvoiceFreeText><%= freeText %></InvoiceFreeText>
       %>, _
       Nothing)
%>
```

The error message says: An embedded expression cannot be used here.

How should I do this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pointing out that you are already in an expression.  You can put your query inside standard parentheses `()` instead of the expression embedding `<%= %>`.

Also, use the `If()` *operator* instead of `IIf()` *function* so you do not always evaluate both branches.